# Generating Distribution provision profile for APNS (Confusing in Two certificate)

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning

I am facing problem in generating the distribution provision profile for APNS.

Currently What i am doing

1. Creating App id and configuring this id for APNS
2. Generating certificate (using "App store and Ad Hoc " option) 
   Now i have Two certificates in Certificates list (APNs production ios & ios Distribution)
3. Finally generating Provision profile using app id and Certificate(ios distribution certificate)

The above steps i am doing for Distribution

Now my Questions are 
1. I have two certificate. which one is to use to create .pem file ?
2. Do I need to install both certificate in keyChain ?

Please help me

Comment: have you seen this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: @viperking yeah, I refer this for development it was working fine . but while in creating distribution file there are two certificate there i stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to install both certificates.
Each certificate is needed for that particular provision profile to be valid.
Appstore provision profile can be used for uploading the binary to iTunes connect.
Adhoc you can use for generating binary that could be installed in certain devices that you added in the provision profile.Both the cases APNs will work.

Comment: got your point ,Thanks. now i have two certificates(APNs production ios & ios Distribution) which one is to use to create .pem file for APNS ?

Comment: Use APNs production certificate.

Comment: Praveen thanks for your help. You said that we need to install both certificate but APNs production certificate we have to use at server side. why we need to install in system? didnt get this

Comment: After installing APN certificate in system keychain we have to take .p12 of the same along with creating .pem using the same certificate.You have to install both the files in server.